# Getting a NullExceptionPointer on my setOnClickListener()

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a NullException error on my Button setOnClickListener() method. I'm a bit flabbergasted as to why this is happening. Please bear in my mind that this is my first Android app, and I assume that there are bound to be some runtime errors (there are no compilation errors).

```
btnNaira.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           dollarToNaira();
        }
});
```

The dollarToNaira() method can be found here:

```
public void dollarToNaira() {

        try {
            dollarAmt = txtAmount.getText().toString();
            nairaAmt = (Double.parseDouble(dollarAmt) * 199.00);
            lblOutput.setText(dollarAmt + "U.S. Dollars = " + nairaAmt + " Nigerian Naira.");
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            message = "Please enter a valid numerical amount";
            lblOutput.setText(message);
        }finally {
            txtAmount.requestFocus();
            txtAmount.selectAll();
        }
    }
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong I would like to know what causes the setOnClickListener method to return NULL. Thanks!

**EDIT: this is the entire onCreate() method, I don't believe that I made an error:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        txtAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
        btnNaira = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNaira);
        btnCFA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCFA);
        lblOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //set up event listener on btnNaira and btnCFA

        btnNaira.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dollarToNaira();
            }
        });


        btnCFA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dollarToCFA();
            }
        });


                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace as well as the code around the  seOnClickListener method call

Comment: Also Add code before setOnclickListener, I doubt that you haven't initialized the button/view

Comment: Hello, I had already initialized the button/View. I don't understand why I have been experiencing this error. Like you guys have said, my code has no errors and looks flawless. So something must be wrong for it to be getting a run-time error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write in this way

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
        btnNaira = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNaira);
        btnCFA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCFA);
        lblOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
```

Make sure you call   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` before initialize your button View.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent, that did indeed work. Is there any particular reason why setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) has to go before the button declarations. Actually, nvm I think I know why. The setContentView() method if I'm not mistaking practically sets the output so it's important to call that method first right? Thanks John Joe! Sad that it just required I move 2 lines of code ROFLLLL. Everything else was fine and I was pulling my hairs out over this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem in your code.
i guess you've made a mistake in initializing buttons and text views.

1- make sure that you define your listener inside a method, like `onCreate()`,
i think you had defined that in class body.

2- i guess that you had defined your button or text views,
but you did not initialized them , so they are null.
here is an example of initializing a **Button**

```
  Button btnDoSomething = (Button)findViewById(R.id.idOfButton);
```

now you can `setOnClickListener` for it .

Comment: I added the onCreate() method to the original post. Please have a look. Thanks Rahmat!

Comment: congratulations your problem was solved, i looked that ,as [John Joe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5156075/john-joe) said: "**Make sure you call  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); before initialize your button View."** ,

Comment: Thanks Rahmat. I'll keep that in mind for the future.